# Integer Linear Programming 3D constraints

Tags: 3d, integer, linear-programming

I have only done basic 2D ILP, but I am wondering how I could apply it to 3D volumetric cube stacking program. I am confused as to how I should set up the problem. Are there any resources that are publicly available to assist me. Thanks.

Comment: ILP has nothing to do with the application, right ? You can use ILP for things that are not even related to images, right ?

Comment: Yes, ILP with 3D constraints.

Comment: with 12504-D constraints as well. When I say "not even related to images", I mean "neither images nor 3D volumetric data". If you don't describe what you want to do, and why you are so specific about imaging applications (you can use ILP to determine production units in a factory for instance), we won't guess it for you. Are you working on the pixel/voxel grid or on super-pixels/voxels ? What is your goal ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I am trying to implement something like this programmatically. {Pages: [1](http://link.springer.com/static-content/0.6342/lookinside/68/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01178968/000.png), [2](http://link.springer.com/static-content/0.6342/lookinside/68/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01178968/001.png), [3](http://link.springer.com/static-content/0.6342/lookinside/68/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01178968/002.png), [4](http://link.springer.com/static-content/0.6342/lookinside/68/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01178968/003.png), [5](http://link.springer.com/static-content/0.6342/lookinside/68/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01178968/004.png)}